TOTP authenticator
I have a Debian Linux desktop PC.
I wish to run a TOTP Authenticator on this platform.
I have found two possibilities in Snap Store :-
Authme and SMART 2fa authenticator TOTP.
However I have not been able to find any documentation about how to run either of these authenticators.
Can anyone help please ?

Did you install and launch them? Are you expecting it to be any more complicated than that?

Since you’re running Debian, you’d be better off looking for authenticators packaged in Debian rather than in the Snap Store. There are a couple of authenticators with graphical user interfaces available in Debian 12:

Numberstation
OTPClient

Once installed, you can start Numberstation by looking for “Numberstation” or “Authenticator” in the application launcher, and OTPClient by looking for “OTPClient”.

To add to Stephen's list,

KeepassXC (sudo apt install keepassxc) is a local, very popular, cross platform, password manager, which has a synchronization mechanism (should you want to exchange passwords between installations on different machines, e.g. via SSH/SFTP), and mostly, it has good browser integration in firefox, chromium/chrome, and Vivaldi (considering your username, that one is probably the relevant one for your).When you set up a new credential set (URL/user name/password), you can also right-click on the entry to set up a TOTP authenticator for that website. Works pretty solidly.

